# Using a postgres composite field containing a geography type for django ORM usage

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, psycopg2

So i have a composite field that i want to use in my django models using postgres as the DB.

```
CREATE TYPE address_verbose AS (

    contact_person_name string_not_null,
    mobile string_no_spaces,
    mobile_cc string_no_spaces,
    email email_with_check,
    address text,
    city text,
    state text,
    country text,
    pincode string_no_spaces,
    location geography

);
```

The `string_not_null`, `string_no_spaces` and `email_with_check` are just domains i have created for validation.

Everything works fantastically if i use SQL, but the thing is want to use this field in a django models and i want to use Django ORM for at least creating, updating and deleting objects containing this field.

So after some google search i was able to come up with a custom model field.

```
from typing import Optional

from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.db import connection
from django.db import models
from psycopg2.extensions import register_adapter, adapt, AsIs
from psycopg2.extras import register_composite

address_verbose = register_composite(
    'address_verbose',
    connection.cursor().cursor,
    globally=True
).type


def address_verbose_adapter(value):

    return AsIs("(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(%s %s)', 4326))::address_verbose" % (
        adapt(value.contact_person_name).getquoted().decode('utf-8'),
        adapt(value.mobile).getquoted().decode('utf-8'),
        adapt(value.mobile_cc).getquoted().decode('utf-8'),
        adapt(value.email).getquoted().decode('utf-8'),
        adapt(value.address).getquoted().decode('utf-8'),
        adapt(value.city).getquoted().decode('utf-8'),
        adapt(value.state).getquoted().decode('utf-8'),
        adapt(value.country).getquoted().decode('utf-8'),
        adapt(value.pincode).getquoted().decode('utf-8'),
        adapt(value.location).getquoted().decode('utf-8'),

    ))


register_adapter(address_verbose, address_verbose_adapter)


class AddressVerbose:
    def __init__(self, contact_person_name: str, mobile: str, mobile_cc: str, email: str, address: str, city: str,
                 state: str, country: str, pincode: str, location: Optional[Point] = None):
        self.contact_person_name = contact_person_name
        self.mobile = mobile
        self.mobile_cc = mobile_cc
        self.email = email
        self.address = address
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.country = country
        self.pincode = pincode
        self.location = location


class AddressVerboseField(models.Field):
    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is None:
            return value
        return AddressVerbose(
            value.contact_person_name,
            value.mobile,
            value.mobile_cc,
            value.email,
            value.address,
            value.city,
            value.state,
            value.country,
            value.pincode,
            value.location,
        )

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, AddressVerbose):
            return value

        if value is None:
            return value

        return AddressVerbose(
            value.contact_person_name,
            value.mobile,
            value.mobile_cc,
            value.email,
            value.address,
            value.city,
            value.state,
            value.country,
            value.pincode,
            value.location,
        )


    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, AddressVerbose):
            return None

        return (
            value.contact_person_name,
            value.mobile,
            value.mobile_cc,
            value.email,
            value.address,
            value.city,
            value.state,
            value.country,
            value.pincode,
            # Attempt 1
            value.location,
            # Attempt 2
            # "ST_GeomFromText('POINT(%s %s)', 4326)" % (value.location[0], value.location[1]) 
        )

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'address_verbose'
```

And a minimal model that uses above field is

```
class Shipment(models.Model):
    pickup_detail = AddressVerboseField()
    drop_detail = AddressVerboseField()
```

Everything works completely fine in creating, updating or fetching a shipment object
if i was to remove the location field. But things start breaking when you include the location field in `AddressVerboseField`.
From django doc, i got the idea to fiddle with `get_prep_value`, and i tried the first approach by directly sending the location as is in the tuple. But it raised the
following error.

[image]

Seems the adapt function from psycopg2 was unable to parse the Point field, so thought of
directly sending the SQL text for a point field in attempt 2. This got me close but the presence of a additional quote in the sql generated broke.

[image]

I have searched quite a lot in google about adapting the composite field of postgres to django, but all results dont really include the fields present in postgis part of the postgres.
This is my first time writing a django custom field, so i might be missing or incorrect on some logic there.
It would be really hepfull if someone could help me out on this or maybe point me out in the right direction.
Thanks